# Are there more output buffers?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

Are there more output buffers? If so, does `endl` only flush the output buffer which is associated with `cout`? If there is only one buffer, then what makes the two objects `cerr` and `clog` distinct?

Comment: Here's a [windows-specific buffer creation function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682122(v=vs.85).aspx). It's like having a back buffer for drawing. The remarks section explains the purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`endl` flushes the output buffer of whichever stream you stream it to. For example:

```
cout << ... << endl;   // flushes the output buffer of 'cout'
cerr << ... << endl;   // flushes the output buffer of 'cerr'
ofstream file("filename");
file << ... << endl;   // flushes the output buffer of 'file'
```

The only difference between `cerr` and `clog` is that `clog` is buffered by default, while `cerr` is not. You can turn buffering on or off for any stream using the `std::unitbuf` and `std::nounitbuf` manipulators. For example:

```
cerr << nounitbuf;   // cerr is now buffered
clog << unitbuf;     // clog is now unbuffered
```

Note that "unitbuf" means "make the buffer size 1", i.e. turn off buffering.

Answer (score 3):

I/O in C (and the UNIX environment it originated with) is done via data "streams" which are abstract sequences of bytes that can be read or written to (or both,) such as files in a filesystem, or devices such as a terminal (or screen and keyboard.)

The C standard library header `<stdio.h>` declares a type `FILE` which serves as a handle for a data stream. It also declares `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` with type `FILE*` to refer to a standard input stream, a standard output stream, and a standard error stream respectively.

The C++ standard library defines `std::istream` and `std::ostream` classes (collectively called iostreams) which can be used to interact with data streams (the terminology is a bit confusing because the C++ iostreams classes are sometimes called simply "streams", but the same word also means the abstract data stream that a `<stdio.h>`FILE` refers to.)

The C++ global `std::istream` object `std::cin` is associated with the standard input stream (i.e. the same stream as `stdin` refers to,) the global `std::ostream` object `std::cout` is associated with the standard output stream, and the global objects `std::cerr` and `std::clog` are distinct objects but are both associated with the standard error stream.

The difference between `cerr` and `clog` is that by default `clog` uses a streambuf that stores characters written to it in an internal buffer and only writes that data to the standard error stream when the buffer fills up or when explicitly flushed, whereas `cerr`'s streambuf does no internal buffering, so everything is written straight to the standard error stream.  Because they are separate objects they have separate streambufs, with different default behaviour, but eventually write to the same standard error stream.

`std::endl` can be written to any `std::ostream`, so if you write `std::cout << std::endl` it will flush the stream associated with `cout`, which is usually the standard output stream.  if you write `std::clog << std::endl` it will flush the stream associated with `clog`, which is usually the standard error stream.

Comment: It should be also noted that cin is `tie()`-d to `cout` by default (and only to it, `cerr` and `clog` aren't connected to it), so reading anything from `cin` automatically flushes `cout`.

Comment: And there's also `sync_with_stdio` that keeps `cin` consistent with `stdin` and `cout` consistent with `stdout` etc. by making them share buffers, but I thought the answer was already long enough!

Comment: This on I didn't know. Anyway, it seems that is is also enabled by default, right?

Comment: Yes, `sync_with_stdio` is true at program startup.